# grails Publisher/Subscriber from domain class to service

Tags: grails

The examples on the web usually have the @Publisher in a service and the @Subscriber also in a service.

I have a @Publisher in a domain class and an @Subscriber in a service. The subscriber never gets called.

```
//domain class
@Publisher
Map testTrigger(){
    return [id:id]
}
//also tried implementing EventPublisher
Map testTrigger(){
    def m= [id:id]
    notify("testTrigger", m)
    return m
}

//service
 @Subscriber
 void testTrigger(Map vals){
   //never triggers
   println "Heard subscriber from #"+vals.id;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think those are only going to work in Spring beans, which your domain class is not.